# WPF: Can I Set IsMouseOver Property of a ChildElement When The Parent Is Moused Over?

Tags: wpf, templates, listbox, styles

Suppose I have a button nested in the `Template` of a `ListBoxItem`, can I set the `IsMouseOver` property of the button to true, so that it looks like its moused over?

Just for illustration, the notifications on the top of the window are what I am referring to. Its basically `ListBoxItem`'s with a `TextBlock` and `Button`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  "IsMouseOver" is readonly.

I'm assuming, though, that you have a custom control template for the Button, right?  If that's the case, one workaround is to mess with the Tag property of the button.  Add a trigger to the ControlTemplate that gets fired when a specific Tag value is set.  Then, in the DataTemplate for your ListBoxItems, just set the button's Tag to that specific value when IsMouseOver on the item is true.  Below is an example:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel x:Name="dp" Background="Transparent">
                <Button x:Name="btn" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="x" Background="Gainsboro">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="bd" Padding="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1"
                                    Background="WhiteSmoke">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="SimulatedMouseOver">
                                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="dp" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Tag" Value="SimulatedMouseOver"/>
                </Trigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <s:String>Item1</s:String>
    <s:String>Item2</s:String>
    <s:String>Item3</s:String>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I am getting the error "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter" my code looks like http://pastebin.com/BUh5YLCD relevant code highlighted.

Also, but if I have a bunch of Setters I want to have, can I group them in a style then reference them?

Comment: "TargetName" can only be set on Triggers that are defined within Templates (e.g. ControlTemplate, DataTemplate).  I assume your DockPanel is part of the DataTemplate for your ListBox.  If this is the case, you need to define an IsMouseOver trigger in that template and move the Setter for the button there.